# Effective Indexing for Lookup Tables in Normalized Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, database-normalization

In a 3NF (SQL Server) database, what column(s) should be indexed (clustered and nonclustered) to improve search efficiency?

Consider the following scenario:
Table1: Employee
          Columns: ID, EmployeeSerial, …columnN
Table2: Job
          Columns: ID, JobCode, …columnN
Table3: Employee_Job
          Columns: ID, Employee_ID, Job_ID

Additional:

- Column “ID” is an automatically incrementing, numeric, primary key in
  each table, but has no business value (think of it as just the record
  number).  It’s only purpose is to join Employee and Job tables.
- The majority of queries performed require data from Employee and Job
  tables, with either or both EmployeeSerial and JobCode specified as
  conditions in the “WHERE” clause.

Follow up question: to get the advantage of the recommended indexing scheme, does the order the 3 tables are joined in the select query matter?

Comment: The columns used for joins should be indexed.  The columns use for equality conditions in `where` clauses should be indexed.  But those are very general guidelines and your question is quite broad.

Comment: If you're just doing inner joins, the order doesn't matter. However if you're using `left/right` joins, the order matters because it fundamentally changes the result sets. You can *force* sql to do things in a certain order, but by default, SQL will figure out whatever it thinks is best. And unless you have a good reason to override that, you should probably just let it do its thing in that regard.

Comment: Tell your instructor, that `ID` in `Employee_Job` is totally useless, an actual Key is `Employee_ID, Job_ID` (which must be defined anyway).

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score -1):

Each `id` should be a primary key, which thereby creates an index.

Then, your typical query would be:

```
select . . .
from employee e join
     employee_job ej
     on ej.employee_id = e.id join
     job j
     on ej.job_id = j.id
where e.serial = ?/j.job_code ?;
```

For this type of query you want additional (non-primary key) indexes on `employee(serial, id)`, `employee_job(employee_id, job_id)`, `job(job_code, id)`, and `employee_job(job_id, employee_id)`.

The order of the tables in the `from` clause has little impact -- and none for three tables.  SQL Server's optimizer does have a limit when optimizing joins, but relevant indexes should always be used, so I think you are safe.